# Regex for label=username and then isolate it

Tags: java, regex, go, grafana

This may be so simple, but im a initiate and i don't find a answer to this.

So this is my test string, i need to convert the username to a label.

I think with this code below i already converted the username as a label.

```
{filename="/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/File.lgw"} |= `]:The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to.`| regexp "(?P<username>)"| line_format "{{.username}}"
```

I am using this Test string on regex101 trying to isolate the username correctly.

```
[Listener 00_TEST_ACCOUNT_LOCK, address 00_TEST-ACCOUNT-LOCK_USER:username]:The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to.
```

I only need keep the beggining part of the code that is:

```
[Listener 00_TEST_ACCOUNT_LOCK, address 00_TEST-ACCOUNT-LOCK_USER:
```

I can add anything to the start and end of the username to better identify it, it can be changed later on to match the server example: --username--

I already tried something so simple as a regular expression of: `.*--` but im stuck there i i don't know what else i can try or if its even good

Comment: You have tagged both Java and the Oracle database and `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, which is a built-in function in Oracle databases. Which language are you using because Oracle databases do not support the same regular expression syntax that java does; they only support a smaller subset.

Answer (score 0):

Because Oracle does not support look at heads you can't do what you want using `regexp_substr`.

However, rather than matching what you *want*, you can match what you * don't* want and replace it with blank, leaning you with what you want:

```
regexp_replace(my_column, ':username.*', ':')
```

Comment: It know my issue, i put wrong TAGS and i have been trying it incorrectly.  Its from Grafana and must be on Golang, sorry im just literally new

Comment: @C0d3r-Initiate what are you trying to say? Do you want to it in Golang instead of oracle?